# Template class inheritance from template types while passing itself

Tags: c++, template-templates, class-template

Can someone please explain what is going on in the code below:

```
template<class Thermo, template<class> class Type>
class thermo
:
    public Thermo,
    public Type<thermo<Thermo, Type>> // <-- this is what I don't get
{
```

Here is what I don't get:

1-class `thermo` inherits from `Type<thermo<Thermo, Type>>` while has a template argument of itself (Type<**thermo**<Thermo, Type>>)

2-`Type` takes itself as an argument in `Type<thermo<Thermo, Type>>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Here is what I don't get:*" Didn't you already correctly describe what this did?

Comment: maybe it helps to think of `Type<thermo<Thermo,Type>>` as a new type that resulted from instantiating `Type` and forget about that it came from the template, call it `B`, then `thermo` inherits from `Thermo` and from `B`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I just described what I saw but I don't understand why/how it works and what is its application in general. For instance, in class thermo, it needs to pass itself. Is it some sort of recursive definition of the class thermo?